# How to punctuate "A and B and C" properly if "B and C" are cohesive, eg 'toast and bacon and eggs' = [toast] and [bacon and eggs]?

Tags: punctuation, conjunctions

Given that "A" is one set and "B" and "C" are cohesive, how should the following phrase be punctuated correctly?

> A and B and C

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a comma in a sentence with multiple “and”s](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94327/using-a-comma-in-a-sentence-with-multiple-ands) and [Sentence with multiple 'and's: should I use an Oxford comma, and if so, where?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60297/sentence-with-multiple-ands-should-i-use-an-oxford-comma-and-if-so-where)

Comment: "Bacon and eggs with toast".

Comment: @HotLicks, this, considered in the abstract, creates the same ambiguity, as it is not obvious whether *and* is of a higher order than *with* or the other way round. If one were not familiar with bacon and eggs, one could wonder whether the order is for bacon-and-eggs with toast or for bacon and eggs-with-toast.

Answer (score 5):

You can write the matched pair with an [ampersand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampersand) instead of the word *and* to indicate that they are closer than the other items in the list:

> We ordered spaghetti and fish & chips.

This usage isn't universal, although Wikipedia notes some specific cases where it's preferred:

> In film credits for stories, screenplays, etc., *&* indicates a closer collaboration than *and.* The ampersand is used by the Writers Guild of America to denote two writers collaborating on a specific script, rather than one writer rewriting another's work. . . .
>
> The ampersand can be used to indicate that the "and" in a listed item is a part of the item's name and not a separator (e.g. "Rock, pop, rhythm & blues, and hip hop").

If you're working with a particular style guide, it may have advice on whether ampersands are preferred (or forbidden) for these kinds of cases.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do it as it stands is *A, and B and C*. Whether that would be clear enough depends on the context. If it wasn't, then you might want to think of some other way of putting it.

Comment: 'Cornflakes, and bacon and eggs' would almost always be read the obvious way because _bacon and eggs_ is such a common collocation. 'Jill and I ordered fish, and chips and peas' probably needs a 'respectively'. You may be forced into 'The four lads ordered fish and chips; fish, chips and peas; fish, chips, peas and gravy; and fish and peas' if you ever write up your diary in a restaurant.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have another question related to punctuations. Please tell me whether the following sentences are correct or not. 01) Innodata is a company that provides BPO and KPO services.  02) Innodata is a company providing BPO and KPO services. 03) Innodata is a company, providing BPO and KPO services.

Comment: Any new question should be created as a NEW question - not within an existing question. BUT a question of the nature "Is this correct?" is off-topic on this site because it is deemed to be merely 'proofreading'. If you can explain why you think a sentence may be wrong or which particular aspect you are having a problem with, then the question my be acceptable. However, you may find [ell.se] more suitable for your basic questions.