# Using commas with multiple "and"s

Tags: punctuation, commas

I have seen this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94327/using-a-comma-in-a-sentence-with-multiple-ands). However, I'm not sure how to leverage that lesson for this particular sentence.
The sentence I'm having trouble with is

> I did this and he and she helped me.

There are two "and"s in this sentence. My intuition tells me it should be

> I did this and he, and she, helped me.

But this still looks wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The comma should precede the **second clause**: *I did this, **and he and she helped me.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma should come after "this".

> I did this, and he and she helped me.

If I can offer an opinion, I'd go with "they" instead of "he and she", if possible.

Comment: Thanks! And, actually, in place of he and she, I have actual names that I'm just introducing. Hence why I kept the "he" and "she." Otherwise, I would have went with your suggestion.